# Compute values to display on the user profile page based on other user profile field values

Tags: 8, users

I've added fields to user profiles:

- subscriber (yes/no)
- guest subscriber (yes/no)
- print subscription expiration date
- online subscription expiration date

On the user profile page, I want to display things like:

- Because you are a guest subscriber, your subscription never expires.
- Your subscription will expire on `date1` [the later of the print and online subscription dates]. Please renew by `date2` for uninterrupted service.
- Your subscription expired `XX days`/`XX weeks`/`XX months` ago on `date`.

These are some examples to give the idea. I need to look at profile field values before the profile is displayed, do some computing, and then add additional, display-only fields to the page or modify the value of existing fields that are displayed on the page.

All I need is a clue about the approach. I already have a custom module, so using something similar to hook_form_alter will do nicely. I've read about 20 posts, but none that seem to match.

Comment: There's more than one way to skin this cat, but one option is to create a custom template for the user profile page. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835931/how-to-add-custom-html-on-user-profile-page-in-drupal-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can make use of hook_entity_extra_field_info() . Below is the following code snippet which you can use in your module:**

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_extra_field_info().
 */
function my_module_entity_extra_field_info() {
  $extra = array();

    $extra['your_entity']['your_content_type']['display']['my_own_pseudo_field'] = array(
      'label' => t('My own field'),
      'description' => t('This is my own pseudo-field'),
      'weight' => 100,
      'visible' => TRUE,
    );
  }

  return $extra;
}
And you can use hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view
/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view().
 */
function my_module_your_entity_view(array &$build, EntityInterface $entity, EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode) {
  if ($display->getComponent('my_own_pseudo_field')) {
      $build['my_own_pseudo_field'] = [
        '#type' => 'markup',
        '#markup' => 'This is my custom content', 
    ];
  }
}
```

Please replace the entity and entity type with your requirement. Since it is only for the display this code snippet will work . Clear the cache you will find this field in manage display section .

Comment: Thanks @Shreya Shetty! I'm going to try this. I'll be back with a report.

Comment: @Sheya Shetty--Your solution worked great (after a bit if trial-and-error). I'll mark it as the accepted answer, but I want to share the code I wrote so people can see an actual implementation. Maybe I can add my code as another answer and then, in your accepted answer, you can direct people to my answer with the code in it?

Comment: Yup sure . Thank you for accepting the answer